# Are functions and helper functions treated differently in python?

Tags: python, function

[image: ![enter image description here]

Over here, the main function is g(x) and the helper function is h(). I noticed I can get the output for g(3), simply by binding x=3 and then doing any of the three

1. print(g(x))
2. g(x)
3. z=g(x)

But on the other hand, I noticed h() is outputted only when I type "print(h())". Are my observations correct or did I make a mistake? And also what is the logic behind this weird discrimination?

I like to think of it this way. Usually, if you had a line like "5" or "x=5", python doesn't give an output of 5. But functions have been given a special feature where they are invoked in any of the 3 ways. It's only that this special feature is being 'withdrawn' in the case of helper functions

Comment: You have a line inside the function `g()` that prints. That will cause output any time `g` is called. There is no such line inside `h()`.

Comment: Your `h()` function doesn't print anything, so you shouldn't expect any output.  And the name `h` is only present within the `g` function.  You can't call it from outside of `g`.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have written is equivalent to this:

```
def g(x):
    def h():
        any_name_you_want = 'abc'
        return any_name_you_want
    x += 1
    print("in g(x)", x)
    print(h())
    return x
```

You cannot assign to a non-local variable inside a function. When Python creates the namespace for `h`, `x` is local to `h` because the assignment requires python to add the namespace for x at runtime.

Hence your code is also equivalent to :

```
def g(x):
    def h():
        return 'abc'
    x += 1
    print("in g(x)", x)
    print(h())
    return x
```

To get a sense of what is happening, run the following and then read up on `UnboundLocalError`:

```
def g(x):
    def h():
        x = x
        return x
    x += 1
    print("in g(x)", x)
    print(h())
    return x
```